# Sitecore Instance Manager developer environment setup

Tags: installation, sim

I am looking for a way to keep all IIS settings, modules and Sitecore versions in sync across multiple developer environments in a team setting. Is there a way to use Sitecore Instance Manager (SIM), or other tools, to automate a development environment setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used a powershell script that does everything:

- install SQL databases
- install solr and configure
- configure IIS
- install Sitecore
- build base VS projects

I would suggest investigating powershell. It will give you a lot of flexibility, for example different steps for different teams.

Answer (score 3):

Another options would be to use VMware kind of software to take snapshot of complete installation of a dev machine and then create developer machines using that snapshot.

SIM is not the tool for your requirement. You can use it to create quick instance. But, not a tool provide sync environments across developer machines.