# How to use SIM to setup dev environment for existing Sitecore instance?

Tags: installation, sim

Similar to this question [Sitecore Instance Manager developer environment setup](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/540/sitecore-instance-manager-developer-environment-setup)

How do you setup a new Dev environment to work against an existing Sitecore instance/DB? (e.g. onboarding a new dev)

It appears that SIM wants to always make a new SQL Server DB in addition to getting the base Sitecore files, but I don't want every developer to have their own local Dev DB... they should work against the existing Sitecore Dev instance DB.

Really it'd be great if I could just get the base Sitecore install files, on our machine, then deploy our custom code (e.g. custom ConnectionStrings.config) into that install folder, so it points to the existing Sitecore instance we want to develop against and has our code customizations.

If SIM is not the right tool, what is? How do you go about this? (I'd expect this is an easy question - think of every typical .NET MVC app you've worked on... get latest and click play...)

Comment: How is your dev environment setup? In order to answer this, we'll need that info. Are the databases local, or shared somewhere? What about the indexes? xConnect?

Comment: Is this SIM or SIF? 8.x or 9.x?

Comment: @ChrisAuer it's for 8.x, so SIM. I'd much prefer developers work against a common remote "dev" database (so a remote "dev" Sitecore instance), like you'd do with most typical web app projects.

Comment: @Gatogordo - what I'm calling the "Dev Sitecore" is a Sitecore instance out on a server. I'd like to get a new developer to be able to work against that Sitecore DB with a local IIS site on their laptop (so they can easily deploy locally and test)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

If the "shared" part you want is the database, the easiest way is to install Sitecore and then just update the connection strings after the installation. This will point your installation at the existing databases that you have. You can then delete your new 'empty' databases, or keep them for when you want to switch to "isolated" mode.

Just as a note, working on shared databases can lead to data collisions and file collisions. Most established teams work out a Continuous Integration strategy so that local changes can be isolated, source controlled, and then deployed to a centralized location for testing of collisions.

For example, if you use Unicorn or TDS you can sync with your local database to serialize the items you have changed and share them with the team, and similarly download from source control the changes by other team members and sync into your system.

Comment: Thanks! Right by "shared Sitecore instance" I moreso mean the DB. We have some policies against having SQL Server instances on our laptops, so I'd much prefer a pattern where we can run Sitecore site locally against a remote dev DB.

Comment: Hence it being a problem that SIM seems to insist on installing a new DB every time. If Jon a month after Mike uses SIM to get files locally, but point at the same remote SQL Server instance, then won't it wipe out and replace the relevant DB's on that SQL Server with a new base one? That seems problematic if we're working against the same DB...

Comment: Don't work on shared DBs. While it might be technically possible; just don't do it. Get those policies update for enterprise CMS development (Sitecore).

Comment: @MarkCassidy - do you have an article/documentation that illustrates your suggested approach? I'm gathering that the recommended advice involves investing in multiple tools, isolated dev machines/SQL instances for each dev, and more tooling to keep everyone in sync... "don't work on shared DBs" is not something I'm used to hearing in web development. Just trying to work against an existing Dev Sitecore instance here (out on some server), looking for a straight forward way to do that.

Comment: It's everywhere. I think the important factor here is, to get you away from the mindset that this is just "Web Development". You're about to install and run an enterprise level application with LOTS of moving parts. I'm just trying to prevent you from going down a road that _absolutely_ will lead to hell. Shared DBs lie down that road.

Comment: @MarkCassidy "it's everywhere" - care to share a link? ;) I'd love to be doing it right since like you said there are many moving parts/not as straight forward as here's my code code + there's the DB.

Comment: Start here. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/set-up-sitecore-and-visual-studio-for-development.html. The guide doesn't even consider shared databases as an option, but proceeds to tell you about the tooling you need (TDS or Unicorn).

Comment: The only instance I have ever seen shared instances work is if you have a developer that is never doing any Sitecore development, and is only editing CSHTML files or JS, like a front-end developer. Then it might make sense because they can just have a local IIS site pointed at the database and get the layout working.

Any 'normal' Sitecore development involves changes to the database by defining templates, content structures, security, etc.

Comment: @DonCheadle if you use a shared DB, other developers will constantly break your site. Constantly. I have been doing this for a long time. Its always SQL Express and local DBs.

Answer (score 1):

#### SIM Tool

With your requirement for remote SQL this might not work. But with SIM you can export an existing instance and then import it again on another dev machine.

[image]

[image]

#### PowerShell

I have also used this PowerShell script to create Sitecore 8 instances in CI environments.

https://github.com/patrickperrone/Sitecore-PowerShell-Installer

Comment: So if I go this route... you're saying you basically copy the whole Sitecore inetpub folder and put it on another machine? But then how do you separate out the custom code from the rest of the inetpub files? (e.g. I believe usually you want to keep your custom source in a separate folder during development and then deploying into inetpub)

Comment: Do the backup to a vanilla instance.

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense. So basically copying around the vanilla instance inetpub folder to stick on other machines? Interesting. A bit unrelated... but how would you go about separating custom source code from vanilla install for a site that you inherited? E.g. it's already running somewhere in inetpub with custom code bundled on top of the base instance, and no up-to-date source code repo is available for the site.

Comment: Deploy it with visual studio or CI. If your solution or CI is perfect, you can take any vanilla machine and deploy all it needs to run.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! But what if you inherit a Sitecore app, so all you have is the inetpub site running. Any suggestions for how you would identify the non-vanilla stuff that you'd need to put into CI or source? (since you don't just want to put the entire inetpub/asd/ site into source)

Comment: No. You would need to know that from development. Any dlls or sitecore packages you will need. You could do a beyond compare for the bin folder and app_config vs a vanilla install to get an idea. But you really should know what it actually needed.

Comment: In that case, why not just use beyond compare to compare entire /Website/ folder against a Vanilla instance? I think it can also show files that are different/modified e.g. dll's. But maybe that'd get confusing.

Comment: And you need to know what items you need.  This is why you need to know from dev what needs to be installed. Code and packages. Just gettin all the missing dlls and files is bad practice.

Comment: What do you mean by "items" and "packages" -- are you referring to items defined in Sitecore e.g. in the Sitecore admin side? And in turn are stored in the sitecore DB.

Comment: instead of knowing various packages to get the Sitecore items... why not just use a DB backup? I.e. pull down the master DB and restore it into your local dev DB? (for the 3 relevant Sitecore DB's)

Comment: Certainly could use SQL, but it is not optimum. When you are able to take a vanilla instance and deploy into it. Ending with a proper running website. Then you know exactly what it takes to make your site run. When you are just using SQL, you can't build trusted QA and UAT sites. Since they are just copies of dev. You don't know what is "really" in the DB.

Comment: sorry Chris I moreso had in mind... if we copy the Prod DB's down to QA... then we'd know QA's Sitecore content correctly 100% matches Prod right? (ignoring website files, I know that's not part of DB. Just thinking of Sitecore items/versions)